# Radioactive Isotopes form Compounds? The Hershey-Chase Experiment

Tags: organic-chemistry, bond, biochemistry, radioactivity

Our chemistry teacher taught us last year, that *radioactive isotopes* of elements **don't** form compounds with other elements "*because they're unstable*" and since we're high-schoolers (I'm assuming that's why) she didn't go into details.

But today in our Biology class, we were taught about the Hershey-Chase experiment (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hershey%E2%80%93Chase_experiment) , where we come across radioactive P-32 being incorporated into the phosphate group of nucleic acids and radioactive S-35 being incorporated into amino acids in proteins.

When we reached *that* bit, what our Chem. teacher said came back to me and it conflicted with the idea being propounded in class. Naturally I raised that issue with our Bio teacher, but she said she wasn't sure about' radioactive isotopes not forming chemical bonds', because that was precisely what was happening in the Hershey-Chase experiment.

So can anyone tell me whether:

a) My Chem. teacher was correct (perhaps *within limits*), and that the incorporation of radioactive isotopes in nucleic acids and proteins is a phenomenon that occurs *outside* of the limiting case she mentioned.

b) My Bio. teacher was right. Radioactive isotopes *do* form compounds.

c) None of the above (could you specify why?)

Comment: Your Chem. teacher is quite definitely wrong. Radioactive isotopes surely **do** form compounds; in fact, they form the same compounds as normal isotopes would. They don't differ from normal isotopes at all, except that they are radioactive. Why else [isotope separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotope_separation) would be such a trouble?

Comment: I am radiochemsit, actually your teacher is wrong. Radioactive isotope do form chemical bond with other compound. Very simple example is  2-deoxy-2-(18F)fluoro-D-glucose is a glucose analogue used as Positron imaging agent (PET).

Comment: Multiple elements don't even *have* any stable isotopes and so every atom of the element is necessarily radioactive, yet they still form an abundance of compounds. A simple example would be uranium.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Radioactive isotopes have similar chemical properties to that of nonradioactive element of same atom. They actually do from chemical bond with compound. You even heard the name of radio-pharmaceutical that involved the complex of radioactive metal with ligand or the radioactive isotope is attached to the pharmaceutical through covalent bond.

The simplest example is FDG is 18F-labled glucose analogue.

[image]

Carbon-11 is another radioactive isotope that form covalent bond similar to Carbon-12 and used in Nuclear medicine as PET imaging agent. C11-Methionine is an example used in the field of Nuclear Medicine for the diagnosis of brain tumour

[image]

Iodine-131 is another sample of radioactive isotope that is used for the detection of hypothyroidism and also form bond with compound. Like in metaiodobenzylguanidine is used in neuroblastoma

[image].

I can gave you lots of others examples but i think these are enough for your understanding. I hope, this will be helpful.

Comment: Or, even simpler - how could anybody mine uranium ore (an oxide) if radioactive isotopes did not form compounds - all of the uranium isotopes are unstable.